# Creating column and filtering it in one select statement

Tags: sql, select, where-clause

Wondering if it is possible to creating a new column and filter on that column. The following is an example:

```
SELECT row_number() over (partition by ID order by date asc) row# FROM table1 where row# = 1
```

Thanks!

Comment: please tag your question with the dbms you are using

Answer (score 3):

Some databases support a `QUALIFY` clause which you might be able to use:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM table1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) = 1;
```

On SQL Server, you may use a `TOP 1 WITH TIES` trick:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM table1
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date);
```

More generally, you would have to use a subquery:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM table1 t
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` so your column has to exist before you can use a `WHERE` clause. You could achieve this by making a subquery of the original query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
     (
        SELECT row_number() over (partition by ID order by date asc) row# 
        FROM table1 
     ) a
WHERE a.row# = 1
```